# How to structure this SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, content-management-system

So basically I'm getting notifications of new content on my website. I have 4 tables -

- articles
- media
- updates
- comments

Each table has a set of its own columns (I can include these if anyone wants). There is one distinct column every table has, this is the *timestamp* column (a **big int** formatted column with data from the PHP **time()** function). My solution to getting the last 30 modifications is to select the first 30 rows from these 4 tables ordered by timestamp descending.

Here is the query I have so far, it doesn't work and I'm wondering if someone could help me. -

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` 
UNION SELECT * FROM `media` 
UNION SELECT * FROM `updates` 
UNION SELECT * FROM `comments` 
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC 
LIMIT 30
```

**EDIT:**
I was also using another query before -

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` ,`media` ,`updates` ,`comments` 
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC 
LIMIT 30
```

and kept getting this error -
*Column 'timestamp' in order clause is ambiguous*

**EDIT 2**

I realise now I have to use the *AS* clause in my statement to combine these results into one table.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", you should always then specify the symptoms of it "not working" - does it produce an error message (and if so, what is the exact message)? Does it give you results, but not the results you want (and if so, what results *does* it give you)? Et cetera.

Comment: UNION only works if the tables have the same fields, it will give you an error if each table has a different set of fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*,m.*,u.*,c.* from articles AS a
LEFT JOIN media AS m ON (m.timestamp = a.timestamp)
LEFT JOIN updates AS u ON (u.timestamp = a.timestamp)
LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON (c.timestamp = a.timestamp)
ORDER BY timestamp desc LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Column 'timestamp' in order clause is ambiguous

Comment: I think your example assumes all 4 tables are updated with the same timestamp value?   They might be, but I am not sure that is the case

Answer (score 0):

Your union can work, but only if you can create some sort of common field list.  For example, lets say you have a description field in each table, with different names.   Something like this will work...

```
SELECT TimeStamp,'Articles',Art_desc AS Description FROM articles
UNION ALL
SELECT TimeStamp,'Media',Media_Desc FROM Media
UNION ALL
SELECT TimeStamp,'Updates',Update_Desc FROM Updates
UNION ALL
SELECT TimeStamp,'Comments',Comment FROM Comments
ORDER BY timeStamp DESC LIMIT 30
```

In essence, you are creating result sets of 3 consistent columns, so UNION will work in this case.