# How to structure this SQL query. Combining multiple tables?

Tags: php, sql

**NOTE: This is not a duplicate of [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494392/how-to-structure-this-sql-query)** . I have changed the table structure and need new help with a new query.

So basically I'm getting notifications of new content on my website. I have 4 tables -

- articles
- media
- updates
- comments

Each table has a set of its own columns (I can include these if anyone wants). In my new notification system I am designing, I determine the newest content, by its timestamp. The timestamp value is an integer formatted to [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

I have just changed my table structure, before, my tables all had columns that were similar. An example, both articles and media had the column *id*. The SQL code I was using was this -

```
SELECT a.*,m.*,u.*,c.* from articles AS a
LEFT JOIN media AS m ON (m.mediaTimestamp = a.timestamp)
LEFT JOIN updates AS u ON (u.updateTimestamp = a.timestamp)
LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON (c.commentTimestamp = a.timestamp)
ORDER BY a.timestamp desc LIMIT 30
```

However when doing this, the code would return multiple iterations of a column in the same row (it would return an *id* column for articles and media!). Obviously when I tried to get the data via code, it would give me data for different tables (instead of giving me the article id, it would give me the media id).

My solution to this was to 'pretty' up my code and name all columns in a table (such as articles) with their table prefix (so id would become articleID). However now the above SQL is producing errors. Could someone 'convert'/restructure this SQL for me.

Comment: btw, did you try to correct your query so that a.timestamp become a.articleTimeStamp?

Comment: Yeah I did before, I just realised that this is different code from my original, I was messing around trying to figure it out why it wouldn't work before, and forgot. I understand it now Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT a.*,m.*,u.*,c.* from articles AS a
LEFT JOIN media AS m ON (m.mediaTimestamp = a.articleTimestamp)
LEFT JOIN updates AS u ON (u.updateTimestamp = m.mediaTimestamp)
LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON (c.commentTimestamp = u.updateTimestamp)
ORDER BY a.articleTimestamp desc LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Unknown column 'a.timestamp' in 'on clause' in /home/cryptum1/public_html/weblib/beta/api/content.php on line 81
Remember that no column has the name of timestamp anymore, they are all prefixed with the content type (articleTimestamp, mediaTimestamp etc.)

Comment: Cool this works, another question, how would I get what table the row is originally from?

Comment: Shouldn't all the conditions contain comparisons to `a.articleTimestamp`, like in the original query?

Comment: How would I do this though? Would I have to check if $row[articleTimestamp] != null to find out if it was an article? Currently I have a column in all the tables called contentType.

Comment: I guess you should keep that column contentType, or you could just make an intersection with each table and compare it to null, i guess there is no easy way to do it